# Prevent a virtual function bering overloaded twice in a sub-sub-class

Tags: c++, class, overloading, virtual, derived

I have a base class `Base`, a somewhat more specialized class `SpecializedBase` derived from Base, and subclasses of the latter such as `Derived`.

I implement a virtual function in `SpecialisedBase` which is pure virtual in `Base`. How to be sure that this function is not overloaded in `Derived`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

yes, if you can use C++11, you can write your class like

```
    struct derived {
        virtual void f() final;
    };
```

Comment: but wait, there's more: you can even put `final` after the class name and prevent the entire class from being inherited from.